# I can be quiet/I can shut up

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-usage, idiomatic-language

> A: Am I asking too many questions?
>
> B: Yeah.
>
> A: Okay. Well, I can **be quiet**. It's just, you know, you keep
> coming here, so maybe you're not that bothered by it.

I initially wrote "shut up", but thought it was too rude. But would "be quiet" be natural here as well? Or would it more have a feel of "I can be quiet *sometimes*" and not "I can be quiet *now*" or "I can shut up *now*" or "I can stop talking *now*"?

Comment: To me it's not about being quiet, but about stopping asking (too) many questions.

Comment: All are possible with different nuances.  There are even more possibilities, depending on the register.  "Well, I can keep quiet then."  "Well, I can chill for a while then."  Saying "shut up" is not so much rude, as blunt and implies you have been distinctly rude.

Comment: Telling another person to 'shut up' is rude; referring to yourself doing it is just being blunt.

Comment: "I can stop asking/talking (now)" "I can shut up" "I can be quite" all seem perfectly idiomatic to me and all have the same meaning. "Shut up" is not rude when referring to yourself, but it is more casual. If talking to a business executive (above you) for example, "I can stop talking (now)" or "I can be quiet (now)" would be more appropriate IMO.